# Append to string

Tags: c#, string, string-concatenation

URL is a string, so why can't I concatenate like so:

```
string url = "something";
url + string.Format("group={0}&", Id);
```

Is this because string is a reference type, and it's actually trying to add it to the reference rather than the object?

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several answers mention immutability, and that's not what this is.

The line of code

```
a + b;
```

Is simply not legal as a standalone statement. You will get the error

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Making `System.String` mutable would not change this. Making `+` *mutate one or both of the operands* would not change this. The line of code simply is not legal.

```
a = a + b; // legal
```

To be clear, you can define your own type, define a `+` operator, inside the method of that operator mutate one of the operands (which would probably anger your consumers, mutable type or not), and then return it, and it *still* would not make the standalone line `a + b;` legal. You must use its result in *something* that is involved in one of the above expressions (assignment, call, etc.).

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar;

    public static Foo operator +(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        a.Bar += b.Bar; // horrible mutation
        return new Foo() { Bar = a.Bar };
    }
}

///

Foo a = new Foo() { Bar = 1 };
Foo b = new Foo() { Bar = 2 };
a + b; // still not legal
```

Answer (score 7):

Needs assignment

```
url += string.Format("group={0}&", Id);
```

or

```
url = url + string.Format("group={0}&", Id);
```

Comment: Thanks - but why is this the case?

Comment: Because strings are immutable.

Comment: `url + string.Format("group={0}&", Id);` creates a new string. Strings are immutable, so without assigning the new string to a variable the operation is pointless.

Comment: It is because strings are immutable, you cant change them after creating, you need to always create a new one.

Comment: Ah yes of course! Duh I was only just reading about the reason for stringbuilder

Comment: It has nothing do with immutability. Strings could be completely mutable, but it would be a (likely unexpected) behavior of the addition operator `+` that would be causing the mutation. Mutable or not, that is not what `+` does. It *returns* the result of the operation without modifying the operands. For a mutable type, you could define a `+` operator to do just that (but you probably would not want to).

Comment: @m.edmondson: url + string.Format("group={0}&", Id);   creates a new String object, but if you don't assign it to anything, then it gets discarded. Variables NEVER change unless you assign them.

Answer (score 3):

The `+` operator doesn't change the variable that you use in the expression. It doesn't do that for a numeric value either:

```
int i = 42;
i + 4; // doesn't change the variable i
```

You have to assign the result to a string variable:

```
url = url + string.Format("group={0}&", Id);
```

You can also use the `+=` operator, that will produce the exact same runtime code:

```
url += string.Format("group={0}&", Id);
```

Note that this doesn't change the string, it produces a new string from the two strings. What the code actually does is:

```
string temp = String.Concat(url, string.Format("group={0}&", Id));
url = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
var mynewstring = url + string.Format("group={0}&", Id);
```

To concatenate into `mynewstring`or alternatively

```
url += string.Format("group={0}&", Id);
```

To concatenate into `url`.

The reason is that strings are *immutable*. To [quote MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx):

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be
>   changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it
>   appear as if you can do this.

Comment: `url += string.Format("group={0}&", Id);` should work as well, i believe.

Comment: @Chad seems I was too slow updating my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instances of `System.String` are immutable: any mutating operation on them (which includes concatenation) will produce a *new* instance with the result. If you don't use this value, you won't see the intended effect:

```
string url = "something";
url = url + string.Format("group={0}&", Id);
```

or of course

```
url += string.Format("group={0}&", Id);
```

**Suggestion:** You might want to use [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) instead of doing string concatenations to build your url.

Answer (score 1):

**Strings are immutable**, meaning once one has been created it cannot be modified.  You can however create a new string, which is exactly what the `+` operator does when applied to strings.  Since it creates a new string and does not modify the existing one you will need to assign it like the other answers mention.

This applies to all immutable types, such as integers, e.g.

```
int i = 2;
i + 2; //i is still 2
i = i + 2; //i is now 4
i += 2; //i is now 6
```